# text-shadow looks weird while in transition

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In the following example, when you hover over the navigation bar, it expands. While it expands, the text, text-shadow to be more specific, looks weird.

```css
body {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  margin: 0;
}
#box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(100,150,165);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.075);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
  font-family: arial;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.65);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
#box.narrow {
  width: 15px;
}
#box.narrow:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
#box.narrow:hover .line {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="narrow">
 <span>Homepage</span>
 <div class="line"></div>
 <span>Nav item 1</span>
 <div class="line"></div>
 <span>Nav item 2</span>
 <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

I did some experimenting, and disabling `position: fixed` on the `#box` fixes the problem. Also disabling the `box-shadow` fixes the problem, but I need to keep both of these styles applied.

[image]

Using Chrome 49 (x86) on Win 8.1 Pro (x64)

Comment: No problem with my browser. google chrome 49 has some weird things, like all of the css/html problems I've seen in the past 3 days are related to it.

Comment: Chrome v50.0.2661.18(dev-m) and see nothing wrong either (on Windows 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering is very subtle but I was able to see it in Chrome 49. It is caused by the transition of the `opacity` of the `.line`.

By replacing the `opacity` transition on `.line` with a `border-color` transition the flickering is fixed.

```
.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: border-color .2s;
}
#box.narrow:hover .line {
border-color:rgba(255,255,255,.2)}
```

Comment: I've applied your solution to the demo and it worked, but not my actual navigation bar. That's because I had two more elements in each item; nav icon and a submenu indicator icon. These are font icons, so text-shadow is also applied to them. I also change the opacity of the submenu indicator icon on hover, so the flicker isn't only due to the `.line` element.

I did some more experimenting. Being inspired by your answer, I figured out that the problem is due the the transition of opacity. If I transition color and text-shadow together instead of opacity, I don't see any flickering.